# Can't open dashboard

Tags: windows, docker, zalenium

I'm using Windows and installed Zalenium with the .\prepare.bat

Then, when i try o start Zalenium with:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
-v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos 
--privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

I get an error on the console:
Copying files for Dashboard...

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/seluser/videos/dashboard.html': No such file or directory
```

Everything works except the Dashboard.
What am i doing wrong?
I'm using the latest version.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Zalenium but I found out that the run command on the Zalenium Github page does not work on all systems.

Try this command i use and let me know if it works for

```
*docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged dosel/zalenium start*
```

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly say that it is trying to look for the file in **LINUX like structure "/home/seluser/videos/"** which will not be available on windows.

When you start zalenium, It looks for **dashboard.html** in the mount drive. Without this file **dashboard will not be visible**.

You should use below command in case of windows.

```
 docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 ^
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
      -v /c/Users/your_user_name/temp/videos:/home/seluser/videos ^
      --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

[Zalenium documentation](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/)

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -d -ti --name zalenium -p 4445:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --restart=always --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

worked for me.. dashboard opens on 4445 port